# execution error: The variable display is not defined. (-2753)

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to extract 2 sets of data from a website . However strangely, I'm getting the following error !

Error;

```
0:7: execution error: The variable display is not defined. (-2753)
```

Code :

```
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


word = []
meaning = []
r = requests.get("XYZ.com")
content = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for words in content.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'qWord'}):
    word.append(unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,words.text)))

for word_meanings in content.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'qDef'}):
    meaning.append(unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,word_meanings.text)))

rest_command = 'display notification \"%s\" with title \"%s\"'.format(meaning[0],word[0])
os.system("osascript -e "+ rest_command)
```

The script basically fetches multiples `words` and their `meanings`, stores them in array & then display them as a OSX notification .

Reference for OSX notification : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the AppleScript in the commandline:

```
rest_command = """'display notification "{}" with title "{}"'""".format(meaning[0],word[0])
os.system("osascript -e "+ rest_command)
```

Comment: It works but it print `%s` as the title and description, both . How can that be resolved ?